# How to get number of commits of a repo using GitPython?

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I'm new with GitPython and I would like to get the nomber of commits of a repo.
I am looking to get alternative to "**git rev-list --count HEAD**" in GitPython, is there a specific function to do that ?

I tried to get the list of every commits of the repo to display then it's size, but the last commit only appears.
thanks for help,
Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the code:

```
import git

repo_path = 'foo'
repo = git.Repo(repo_path)
# get all commits reachable from "HEAD"
commits = list(repo.iter_commits('HEAD'))
# get the number of commits
count = len(commits)
```

I'm not familiar with Python 3.x. There may be errors due to differences between Python 2.x and 3.x.

After doing some research, I find we can just invoke `git rev-list --count HEAD` in a direct way.

```
import git

repo_path = 'foo'
repo = git.Repo(repo_path)
count = repo.git.rev_list('--count', 'HEAD')
```

Note that the `-` in the command name should be `_` in the code.

Comment: First example with iter_commits might raise an exeption if there is no commit history (0 commits).

Comment: Your second answer was very helpful, particularly if the result is zero. In my case, I needed all commits and for a date range.
`count = repo.git.rev_list('--count', '--all', since='2023-02-01', until='2023-03-01')`
Thank you @ElpieKay.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of all commits with `iter_commits()`. Iterate over it and count commits

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo()

print(len(list(repo.iter_commits())))
```

Comment: It works now ! thank a lot I didn't try that way before :)